# OpenSSL AES Segmentation Fault on Encrypt Update

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I have string with set size and trying to AES encrypt it, but I get Segmentation Fault at `EVP_EncryptUpdate`

```
size_t dec_len = 20;
char *dec = malloc(dec_len + 1);

//Fill dec
...
//Encrypt

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)" no ";
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, &key, NULL);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
unsigned char *ciphertext;
int ciphertext_len;
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &ciphertext_len, dec, dec_len);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + ciphertext_len, &ciphertext_len);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

I have no idea what's causing this. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you telling OpenSSL to store the ciphertext?

Comment: Is `" no "` a replacement for the actual key, which I assume is actually the correct length and properly generated? If you're just handing random cstrings to this (for example, a password rather than a proper AES key), I wouldn't expect it to work. I would also expect warnings given that you're passing the wrong type (as Andrew notes below). Are you making sure to address all warnings?

Comment: You aslo seem to be passing an uninitialized pointer as ciphertext (which is likely what user253751 is asking as well). That's just going write to random memory. Did you mean to allocate a buffer for ciphertext? (Again, I would expect the compiler to warn you about this used-before-assignment mistake.) I'd start with the OpenSSL examples of how to use these functions. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_EncryptInit_ex.html

Comment: Solved by allocating cipher text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by allocating ciphertext variable.

Comment: Make sure the key you pass in is the correct size, otherwise you won't be able to decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_EncryptInit_ex.html),  is declared as

```
int EVP_EncryptInit_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *type,
    ENGINE *impl, const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *iv);
```

Note that `key` is declared to be `const unsigned char *key`.

But your code is

```
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)" no ";
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, &key, NULL);
```

You are passing the ***address*** of your `key` pointer to the function - an `unsigned char **` instead of a `const unsigned char *`.  You want to pass the address of the string, which is what `key` points to:

```
const unsigned char *key = (const unsigned char *)" no ";
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it didn't do anything. It still segfaulted at `EVP_EncryptUpdate`